# Copying files in Windows is super slow

Tags: batch-file, command-line, windows-7, copy, robocopy

I've made a batch script that uses `robocopy` to duplicate 1 file over and over again (e.g. 9 times):

```
SET filename=some_file.mkv

for /l %%i in (1, 1, 9) do (
    robocopy "." ".\new" "%filename%" :: duplicate
    rename "new\%filename%" "[new%%i] %filename%" :: rename duplicated file
)
```

This works butter smooth for the first few files, but after 4-5 copies, the copying comes to a halt and gets *super* slow.

It doesn't matter if it's through `robocopy` or plain-old Windows GUI copying and pasting.

I can't seem to figure out what the problem is. I have 16GB ram on my computer and although Chrome is using a lot of it, I tried clearing it, but the problem persists.

The only clue I have is that when I have lots of **Free memory** in **Resource Monitor**, the copying works great, but once it goes down to ~0 MB, the copying slows to a crawl.

- Does copying/robocopy in Windows not free up memory once copying is done?
- Is there a toll for duplicating same file multiple times?
- Is there perhaps another problem with my SSD or File Explorer or RAM?
- Is there a better way to do this efficiently?

Any help or clue on what the problem is would be greatly appreciated :)

---

[**[VIDEO]** showing the problem](https://streamable.com/ott2dm)

---

Comment: the ~0MB free when the trouble starts almost certainly means that the processes are being swapped by the OS. (and it may be that you already know this). The times you are seeing are normal for this issue. I get swapping anytime I'm using more that 75% of the 8GB my computer has. Usuallly because I have too many windows open in a browser, and YouTube tabs seem to be the biggest hogs of all. Try adding a 30 second sleep (and then 1 , 2 , 3 mins) to see if the swap problem clears with a little time? Good luck.

Comment: I do not really understand why not using `for /L %%i in (1, 1, 9) do copy "%filename%" "new\[new%%i] %filename%"` to copy the file into already existing subdirectory `new` with the new file name. However, __COPY__ and __ROBOCOPY__ copy files in blocks and not with loading first entire file contents into RAM and then writing the entire file contents to storage media. So only a very small amount of RAM is used by __COPY__ or __ROBOCOPY__ during the file copy. You have too many applications running parallel using much RAM or too many applications running all accessing hard disk at the same time.

Comment: @Mofi you're absolutely right -- just tried running the script and file on my external HDD (1TB), and the copying is soo much faster without any significant slowdowns. Looks like it's indeed my **SSD** bottlenecking the copying. How do I read the Disk graphs in resmon? or how do I check what's accessing my hard disk at any given time to diagnose this? Thanks :)

Comment: I don't use Windows resource monitor. I use free Sysinternals (Microsoft) [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) with added columns __Reads__ and __Writes__ on tab __Process Disk__ of __Select Columns__ dialog. The tool [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) helps to find out which file system accesses are done by those processes with high hard disk activity. Well, __Process Explorer__ and __Resource Monitor__ use the same Windows kernel resources, so there is no real difference here.